# How to replace special character '/' to '_' in a bat file

Tags: batch-file, window

I have a string to represent date "05/28/2015" and would like to change it to '05_28_2015" using bat. Any suggestion would be appreciated ?

```
SET var_date=%date:~4,10%
SET mm = %var_date:~0,2%
SET dd = %var_date:~3,2%
SET yyyy = %var_date:~6,4%
echo %mm%
echo %dd%
echo %yyyy%
echo %mm%_%dd%_%yyyy%
```

Comment: What did you try before post a question here ?

Comment: You should really provide your attempts. You won't learn anything by just asking for answers.

Comment: This is my first question sorry for not following the standards. I was reading the standards and editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've got substring extraction by numeric index pretty well mastered.  Batch variables also have a syntax for variable substring replacement:

```js
%haystack:needle=replacement%
```

will replace all occurrences of "needle" with "replacement" in the variable %haystack%.  With that in mind, you can replace all `/` with `_` using this syntax.

```js
set "var_date=%date:~4,10%"
set "var_date=%var_date:/=_%"
echo %var_date%
```

That should echo `05_28_2015` if you're in the U.S. locale.  There are more locale-agnostic ways of getting MMDDYYYY, but we'll save that lesson for another day.